# JS, Select и Массивы

Tags: javascript, массивы, select, случайные-числа

Нужна ваша помощь. Есть в html'е select с четырьмя пунктами, кнопка и параграф, есть в коде 4 массива. Нужно, чтобы в зависимости от выбранного пункта в селекте при нажатии кнопки, в параграфе рандомно выводилась надпись из соответствующего массива. Да, тут ещё switch-case применить надо бы.

```js
let array1 = ['PHP', 'JavaScript', 'Python', 'Perl', 'Ruby', 'Go', 'Java'];
let array2 = ['Red', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Black', 'White', 'Green', 'Brown'];
let array3 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'];
let array4 = ['BMW', 'Nissan', 'Lada', 'WW', 'Mustang', 'NIVA', 'RR'];

let button = document.getElementById('clickButton');
```

```html
<body>

  <form name="myForm">
    <select name="language" size="1">
      <option value="Array1" selected="selected">Array 1</option>
      <option value="Array2">Array 2</option>
      <option value="Array3">Array 3</option>
      <option value="Array4">Array 4</option>
    </select>
    <p><button id="clickButton">Клик</button></<p>
      <p>Нажми на кнопку</p>
  </form>


  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
```

С одним массивом вопросов нет, функция примитивная. Но вот селект и несколько массивов... никак не могу сориентироваться. Всем заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Можно собрать все массивы в один объект и искать их по его ключам:

```js
let obj = {
  lang: ['PHP', 'JavaScript', 'Python', 'Perl', 'Ruby', 'Go', 'Java'],
  color: ['Red', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Black', 'White', 'Green', 'Brown'],
  number: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'],
  mark: ['BMW', 'Nissan', 'Lada', 'WW', 'Mustang', 'NIVA', 'RR'],
}

let select = document.getElementById('select');
let array; // здесь будет хранится текущий выбранный массив
select.addEventListener('change', function(){
  let key = this.value; 
  // value выбранной опции, который совсем случайно совпадает с ключами объекта
  // Из которого достаем нужный массив по этому ключу:
  array = obj[key]; 
});

let msg = document.getElementById('msg');
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if( !array ) { return; } // Если массив еще не выбрали - функция прерывается

  msg.textContent = "";
  let rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * array.length );  
  setTimeout(function(){
    msg.textContent = array[rand];
  }, 100); // Небольшое мигание при клике.
});
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <select id="select" name="language">
    <option value="lang">Язык Программирования</option>
    <option value="color">Цвет</option>
    <option value="number">Число от 1 до 7</option>
    <option value="mark">Марка Машины</option>
  </select>
  <button id="btn" type="button">Клик</button></<p>
  <p id="msg">Нажми на кнопку</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Обоим огромное спасибо! И за помощь и за оперативность. Жаль карму добавить не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант без свича :

```js
let arrays = {
  array1: ['PHP', 'JavaScript', 'Python', 'Perl', 'Ruby', 'Go', 'Java'],
  array2: ['Red', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Black', 'White', 'Green', 'Brown'],
  array3: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'],
  array4: ['BMW', 'Nissan', 'Lada', 'WW', 'Mustang', 'NIVA', 'RR']
};

let button = document.getElementById('clickButton'),
  getRandomInt = (max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let arrName = document.querySelector('select[name="language"]').value,
    p = document.getElementById('output'),
    arr = arrays[arrName];

  p.textContent = arr[getRandomInt(arr.length)];
});
```

```html
<select name="language" size="1">
  <option value="array1" selected="selected">Array 1</option>
  <option value="array2">Array 2</option>
  <option value="array3">Array 3</option>
  <option value="array4">Array 4</option>
</select>
<p><button id="clickButton">Клик</button></<p>
  <p id="output">Нажми на кнопку</p>
```

Вариант со свичем :

```js
let array1 = ['PHP', 'JavaScript', 'Python', 'Perl', 'Ruby', 'Go', 'Java'],
  array2 = ['Red', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Black', 'White', 'Green', 'Brown'],
  array3 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'],
  array4 = ['BMW', 'Nissan', 'Lada', 'WW', 'Mustang', 'NIVA', 'RR'];

let button = document.getElementById('clickButton');

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let arrName = document.querySelector('select[name="language"]').value;
  let p = document.getElementById('output');
  let res = '';

  switch (arrName) {
    case 'Array1':
      res = array1[getRandomInt(array1.length)];
      break;
    case 'Array2':
      res = array2[getRandomInt(array2.length)];
      break;
    case 'Array3':
      res = array3[getRandomInt(array3.length)];
      break;
    case 'Array4':
      res = array4[getRandomInt(array4.length)];
      break;
  }

  p.textContent = res;
});
```

```html
<select name="language" size="1">
  <option value="Array1" selected="selected">Array 1</option>
  <option value="Array2">Array 2</option>
  <option value="Array3">Array 3</option>
  <option value="Array4">Array 4</option>
</select>
<p><button id="clickButton">Клик</button></<p>
  <p id="output">Нажми на кнопку</p>
```